# What is the pythonic way to print values right aligned?

Tags: format, python

I've a list of strings which I want to group by their suffix and then print the values right-aligned, padding the left side with spaces.

What is the pythonic way to do that?

My current code is:

```
def find_pos(needle, haystack):
    for i, v in enumerate(haystack):
        if str(needle).endswith(v):
            return i
    return -1

# Show only Error and Warning things
search_terms = "Error", "Warning"
errors_list = filter(lambda item: str(item).endswith(search_terms), dir(__builtins__))

# alphabetical sort
errors_list.sort()
# Sort the list so Errors come before Warnings
errors_list.sort(lambda x, y: find_pos(x, search_terms) - find_pos(y, search_terms))

# Format for right-aligning the string
size = str(len(max(errors_list, key=len)))
fmt = "{:>" + size + "s}"
for item in errors_list:
    print fmt.format(item)
```

An alternative I had in mind was:

```
size = len(max(errors_list, key=len))
for item in errors_list:
    print str.rjust(item, size)
```

I'm still learning Python, so other suggestions about improving the code is welcome too.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

1. The two sorting steps can be combined into one:

   ```
   errors_list.sort(key=lambda x: (x, find_pos(x, search_terms)))
   ```

   Generally, using the `key` parameter is preferred over using `cmp`. [Documentation on sorting](http://wiki.python.org/moin/HowTo/Sorting)
2. If you are interested in the length anyway, using the `key` parameter to `max()` is a bit pointless.  I'd go for

   ```
   width = max(map(len, errors_list))
   ```
3. Since the length does not change inside the loop, I'd prepare the format string only once:

   ```
   right_align = ">{}".format(width)
   ```
4. Inside the loop, you can now do with the free [`format()` function](http://docs.python.org/library/functions.html#format) (i.e. not the `str` method, but the built-in function):

   ```
   for item in errors_list:
       print format(item, right_align)
   ```
5. `str.rjust(item, size)` is usually and preferrably written as `item.rjust(size)`.

Comment: Is (4) in any way better or more pythonic than `str.format`? The format used in it, and (3) looks a bit weird to me. Thanks for the other points, I really appreciate it.

Comment: @Lekensteyn: `str.format()` formats all replacement fields in the template string using `format()`.  The format specifier embedded in the each replacement string is passed as second parameter to `format()`.  For example, `"x {:5d} x {:>6} x".format(123, "abc")` will format the first field by calling `format(123, "5d")` and the second field by `format("abc", ">6")`.  If you only want to format a single field, you simply don't need a template string.  It's more direct and more concise to call `format()` right away.  Asking if this is more "Pythonic" is completely meaningless in this context.

Comment: thanks for the clarification, I'll accept this answer as it's more detailed than Ignacio' one.

Answer (score 8):

Very close.

```
fmt = "{:>{size}s}"
for item in errors_list:
    print fmt.format(item, size=size)
```

Comment: Thanks, I didn't know that those fields could be recursively added. Are the other parts of my code pythonic enough?

Comment: You sort twice which is a bit silly, but the rest is acceptable.

Comment: Silly? Isn't that the recommended way to sort by a primary and then a secondary key? Ref. [Note 9](http://docs.python.org/library/stdtypes.html#mutable-sequence-types)

Comment: Recommended, no. The way to do it is to use a tuple as a key with the relevant criteria as elements.

Comment: I don't think the sort is silly at all. It results in errors sorted alphabetically following by warnings sorted alphabetically. A more complex key function could do that with a single sort but unless this is a critical code hotspot just doing separate sorts for each key needs a lot less thinking. However, using `find_pos()` to generate a key instead of writing a comparison function would be a lot more Pythonic.

Answer (score 1):

You might want to look [here](http://docs.python.org/tutorial/inputoutput.html#fancier-output-formatting), which describes how to right-justify using str.rjust and using print formatting.